# Playframework catch a WS timeout and retry X times

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

There is not a lot of documentation about how to handle exceptions for WS. Specifically I would like to get a URL with a timeout and to try again that same url up to 5 times. I tried (simplistically) to nest in .recover but no luck.

```
 val wsParams = WS.url(destinationUrl).withTimeout(5000)

 val weResponse = wsParams.get().recover(
      wsParams.get()
 )
```

This throws: type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response] required: PartialFunction[Throwable,?]

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to recover a future with another future, you have to use `recoverWith`:

```
wsParams.get().recoverWith {
  case ex: ConnectException => wsParams.get()
  case ex: SSLException     => // do something else
}
```

Comment: Is recoverWith something new in 2.3. We are only running 2.2.2 which provide documentation for .recover as a function. Either way I still can't get either example to compile. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Both `recover` and `recoverWith` are defined on `Future` which comes from Scala, not Play: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future

Comment: I get it, you are right. Though in either case, recoverWith and recover, doing a second call to WS.get() is going to return a Future not a Throwable, which is what seems to be expected?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library with success: https://github.com/softprops/retry

EX:

```
// define your success condition
implicit val success = new retry.Success[WSResponse](r => !((500 to 599)  contains r.status))
// retry 3 times pausing 30 seconds in between attempts
val future = retry.Pause(3, 30.seconds) { () =>
  WS.url("theUrl").post("postdata")
}
```